# How do I, using jQuery, select the table when I have "this" from within the table

Tags: jquery

I have a javascript function that receives "this" which would be an element within a table.  The element might be anything withing the table.  What I want to do is to select the table that "this" is in.

```
function myfunc(element)
{
  var theTable = $(....
}
```

What is a succinct way of doing this?

Comment: `var theTable = this.offsetParent` will get you the table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
var theTable = $(this).closest("table");
```

It will walk the ancestor chain from the element in `this` (*inclusive*) and return the first element that matches the selector.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
function myfunc(element)
{
  var theTable = $(this).closest('table')
}
```